# How can I show my profile picture from the database?

Tags: django

The photo is uploaded and saved in the database but I can't show the picture in the template. Now, what can I do? Where is the problem? What will be the logic?

***Settings:***

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

***Urls:***

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('business_app.urls')),

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

***Views:***

```
def change_profile_picture(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            profile_picture = request.FILES['profile_picture'] if 'profile_picture' in request.FILES else None

            user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.user.pk)
            if request.user.pk != user.pk:
                return redirect("/")

            Profile_picture.objects.create(
                Profile_picture = profile_picture,
                USer = request.user,
                )        

            return redirect("/")
    return render(request,'0_index.html')
```

***Models:***

```
class Profile_picture(models.Model):
    USer = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_propic")
    Profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="3_profile_picture/",default='3_profile_picture/avatar.png', null=True, blank=True)
```

***templates:***

```
<img src="static/1_images/3_about.jpg" alt="" width="100"
                                        class="img-fluid rounded-circle mb-3 img-thumbnail shadow-sm">
```

Comment: Is the code snippet you gave of your template in `/` or in `0_index.html`?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to pass your `Profile_picture` object to your template like so, with `new_pf` being an instance of that object:

`views.py`

```
return render(request,'your_html_page.html', {'pf': new_pf})
```

Then in your template `your_html_page.html`:

```
<img src="{{ pf.Profile_picture.url }}">
```

In your template you are referring to your `Profile_picture` instance with `pf`, then accessing the `Profile_picture` attribute, then accessing the [built-in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField) `url` attribute to get the url which the browser will display as a picture.